# How to change origin of elements based on another elements in ios

Tags: ios, uielementcollection

Sorry guys one simple doubt but i could not find any answer. My problem is i want to change the origin of element based on another elements. To be more correct for example if i have three labels, i set each labels in same x axis but different y axis one by one. if first label content increases second and third label's y axis should automatically increase. so how i can calculate it..

```
 UILabel *label1 =[[ UILabel alloc]init];
label1.frame=CGRectMake(10, 50, 10, 150);
label1.text=@"Favorite Cuisine ";

[ViewProfileResultSrollview addSubview: label1];

[label1 sizeToFit];
label1.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];

UILabel *label2 =[[ UILabel alloc]init];
label2.frame=CGRectMake(10, 80, 10, 150);
label2.text=@"Preferred Dress Style";

[ViewProfileResultSrollview addSubview: label2];

[label2 sizeToFit];
label2.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];

UILabel *label3 =[[ UILabel alloc]init];
label3.frame=CGRectMake(10, 120, 10, 150);
label3.text=@"Spoken Languages";

[ViewProfileResultSrollview addSubview: label3];

[label3 sizeToFit];
label3.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the previous frame, since you are using `[label1 sizeToFit];`

Example below for label 2:

```
UILabel *label2 =[[ UILabel alloc]init];
label2.frame=CGRectMake(10, label1.frame.origin.y+label1.frame.size.height+30, 10, 150);
label2.text=@"Preferred Dress Style";
```

Comment: k if i did not use size to fit am just displaying a paragraph in label by setting number of lines method now how i can calculate the origin

Comment: Then you should use [label1.text sizeWithFont:label1.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(label1.frame.size.width, 9999)]; this will get you the height of the text dependent on the label1's font and width.

Comment: My final question how i can restrict height of scrollview based on third label's originViewProfileResultSrollview.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,1000);
    
   [ViewProfileResultSrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 3500)];

Answer (score 0):

You can make it easy:

```
float        currHeight = 7.0;
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0, currHeight, self.view.frame.size.width, 0.0)];
[label setText: @"your text"];
[label sizeToFit];

CGRect labelFrame = label.frame;
labelFrame.size.height = label.contentSize.height;
label.frame            = labelFrame;

[self.view addSubview: label];

currHeight += label.frame.size.height + 5;
```

And you can use currHeight for your other labels!

Hope it will help!

Comment: k if i did not use size to fit am just displaying a paragraph in label by setting number of lines method now how i can calculate the origin